# Handling state change in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, react-props

I'm making a youtube clone, and it's made of three basic parts: the input box to search, the main video that will be played, and the video list. But I'm having a trouble: everytime I click another video in the list it doesn't replace the old one. The function handleVideoSelection is responsilble for that. Can someone help me??

When I console.log the selectedVideo in the App, it works, but in the other components no

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react';
import { Container, SearchWrapper, VideosWrapper } from './Layout'
import GlobalStyles from './styles/GlobalStyles'

import Search from './components/Search';
import MainVideo from './components/MainVideo';
import VideoList from './components/VideoList';

import axios from 'axios'

interface Video {
    id: {
    videoId: string;
  };
  snippet: {
    channelTitle: string;
    description: string;
    thumbnails: {
      high: { 
        url: string 
      }
    }
  }
}


const App:React.FC = () => {

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('')
  const [results, setResults] = useState<Video[]>([])
  const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState<Video>({} as Video)

  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value)
  } 

  const handleVideoSelection = (id: string) => {
    const video = results.find(video => video.id.videoId = id)

    setSelectedVideo(video as Video)
  }
 
  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    const baseUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search'
    const key = 'MyKey' // I already have it, this is not the problem
    const maxResults = 5
    const part = 'snippet'

    axios.get(`${baseUrl}?key=${key}&q=${inputValue}&maxResults=${maxResults}&part=${part}`)
    .then(res => setResults(res.data.items))

    setInputValue('')
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <SearchWrapper>
        <Search 
          inputValue={inputValue} 
          handleChange={handleChange} 
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit} 
        />
      </SearchWrapper>

      <VideosWrapper>
        <MainVideo video={selectedVideo} />
        <VideoList videos={results} handleVideoSelection={handleVideoSelection} />
      </VideosWrapper>

      <GlobalStyles />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

VideoList.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

import { ListContainer, ListWrapper, Miniature } from './styles'

interface Video {
  id: {
    videoId: string;
  };
  snippet: {
    channelTitle: string;
    description: string;
    thumbnails: {
      high: { 
        url: string 
      }
    }
  }
}

interface Props {
  videos: Video[];
  handleVideoSelection(id: string): void;
}

const VideoList:React.FC<Props> = ({ videos, handleVideoSelection }) => {

  return (
    <ListContainer>
      <ListWrapper>
        {videos.map(video => (
          <Miniature onClick={() => handleVideoSelection(video.id.videoId)} key={video.id.videoId} />
        ))}
      </ListWrapper>
    </ListContainer>
  )
}

export default VideoList
```

MainVideo

```
import React from 'react'

import { VideoContainer, VideoWrapper, Video, Info } from './styles'

interface Video {
  video: {
    id: {
    videoId: string;
  };
  snippet: {
    channelTitle: string;
    description: string;
    thumbnails: {
      high: { 
        url: string 
      }
    }
  }
  }
}


const MainVideo = ({ video }: Video) => {

  console.log(video.id)

  return (
    <VideoContainer>
      <VideoWrapper>
        <Video />
        <Info />
      </VideoWrapper>
    </VideoContainer>
  )
}

export default MainVideo
```

Comment: So, if you `console.log` the `selectedVideo` inside your `handleVideoSelection`, does that ID updates correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't know what is happening

Comment: Could you fix the `results.find(video => video.id.videoId = id)` to `results.find(video => video.id.videoId === id)`, otherwise it just changes the id of the first video to match the selected one